# Impala-shell Command Argument List Too Long

Tags: linux, sh, impala

I have a 1,700 lines query to be executed in Impala-shell. I created a shell script with below command:

`impala-shell -V -i hostname -q "[QUERY]"`

However, when I executed it using `sh script.sh`, I got the error message `"Argument list too long"`. I am able to run simpler/short query using Impala-shell command.

I also tried to enlarge the limit by running command `ulimit -s 65536` but I got the same error.

I suspect the number of lines of the query is too big.

Comment: There is indeed a limit to the number of arguments. You can get is with ``getconf ARG_MAX``. Can you split your ``QUERY`` ?

Comment: Maybe the `-f` option is what you need?  `The -f option lets you process a file containing multiple SQL statements, such as a set of reports or DDL statements to create a group of tables and views.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-f option is the answer. I prepared a separate SQL file and it worked.
`impala-shell -V -i hostname -f file.sql`